# F# async and let! confusion

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I am confused about the

```
let decode buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)
```

line, what is going on there ?

buffer is declared inside async, or is it a closure ?

https://github.com/sebfia/OffLog/blob/master/Shared/FeedStorage.fs#L22

```
 let thaw<'T> path =
     let decode buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)

     async {
         try
             match File.Exists(path) with

             | false -> return None

             | true ->
                 use fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
                 let! buffer = fs.AsyncRead(fs.Length |> Convert.ToInt32)
                 let str = decode buffer
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(str)

                 let bla = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'T>(str)

                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(typeof<'T>.GetType().FullName)
                 return bla |> Some

         with | e -> System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString()); return None

     }
```

Comment: `let decode buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)` is a local function taking `byte[]` (buffer) and returning `string`. `buffer` under async is another value that happens to have (unfortunately) the same name.

Comment: Perhaps you would benefit from rephrasing your question in a more clear way.

Comment: ah right, got it now. thanks @Petr. Got confused when I see the whole decode function is declared on one line, instead of on 2 lines!